Volume around $y$ axis
To find the volume of the solid of revolution around $y$ bounded by
$$y=x^2,\quad y=x-2$$
and the lines $y=0$ and $y=1$, I did as follows: since the region is

Then, the volume is:
$$2\pi\cdot\left(\int_{0}^{1}x^3 dx+\int_{1}^{2}xdx+\int_{2}^{3}x(3-x)dx\right)=\frac{35\pi}{6}$$

Why don’t you see if you get the same with the washer method on $y \in [0,1]$ to verify?

@RobinSparrow All I want is to know if it's correct, thanks.

It looks fine. But it would have taken less time than typing the post to do the integration on y via washer to see if you independently got the same answer…

Below is an alternative approach, leading to the same result.
You can first calculate the volume of the solid of revolution around $y$ bounded by
$$y=x^2,\quad y=1,\quad x=0,$$
and then calculate the volume of the frustum of the cone, finally calculate the difference between the two.
The volume of the solid of revolution around $y$ bounded by
$$y=x^2,\quad y=1,\quad x=0$$
is
$$\pi\int_0^1 ydy=\left.\frac\pi2y^2\right|_0^1=\frac\pi2.$$
The volume of the frustum of the cone is
$$\frac13\pi\cdot3^2\cdot3-\frac13\pi\cdot2^2\cdot2=\frac{19}3\pi.$$
Finally, the desired volume is
$$\frac{19}3\pi-\frac\pi2=\boxed{\frac{35}6\pi}.$$
We get the same answer.
